# App enters in loop while during localization

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I think my app enters loop because once it starts in device, it doesn't respond to any commands including lisener the button. I believe that the problem is the methods for permits in RunTime. I'm sorry for my English.
My code is:

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

```
private static final int REQUEST_RESOLVE_ERROR = 3;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private volatile Location mCurrentLocation;
private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSION_LOCATE = 2;
private static final int LOCATION_DURATE_TIME = 5000;
private boolean mResolvingError = false;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ciao", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "connesso", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    manageLocationPermission();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

//gestione dell'errore
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult)
{
    if (mResolvingError) {
        // If we're already managing an error we skip the invocation of this method
        return;
    } else if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
        // Here we check if the ConnectionResult has already the solution. If it has
        // we start the resolution process
        try {
            // Starting resolution
            mResolvingError = true;
            // We launch the Intent using a request id
            connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(MainActivity.this, REQUEST_RESOLVE_ERROR);
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            // If we have an error during resolution we can start again.
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    } else {
        // The ConnectionResult in the worse case has the error code we have to manage
        // into a Dialog
        // Starting resolution
        mResolvingError = true;
    }
}



//location update
private void updateLocation()
{
    LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
            .setNumUpdates(1)
            .setExpirationDuration(LOCATION_DURATE_TIME);


    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
            .requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, locationRequest, new LocationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
                {
                    mCurrentLocation = location;
                }
            });
}

private void startLocationListener()
{
    updateLocation();
}


//permessi in RunTime
private void manageLocationPermission()
{
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION))
        {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("Permesso di geolocalizzazione")
                    .setMessage("Devi dare il permesso alla geolocalizzazione")
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_PERMISSION_LOCATE);
                        }
                    })
                    .create()
                    .show();
        }
        else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_PERMISSION_LOCATE);
        }
    }else
    {
        mCurrentLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        manageLocationPermission();
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults)
{
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    if(requestCode == REQUEST_PERMISSION_LOCATE)
    {
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            //se mi hanno accettato i permessi
            startLocationListener();
        }
        else{
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("Permesso di geolocalizzazione")
                    .setMessage("Devi dare il permesso alla geolocalizzazione")
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            finish();
                        }
                    })
                    .create()
                    .show();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: If you're constantly entering the catch statement in `onConnectionFailed`, that could be the infinite-loop. Can you debug/log and see if your code is entering that code over and over again?

Comment: i've tried the comment the code and I find out that the problems are the codes of permissions at runtime, but I do not understand what is ..

Comment: What android version are you running on?

Comment: android 7.1.1 - API 25

Comment: I think i saw what causes the infinite loop, check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

If manageLocationPermission() is called with the permissions already granted, your code enters the following else clause

```
} else {
    mCurrentLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    manageLocationPermission();
}
```

Here you're calling the same function again, and since the permissions are granted, you will enter the same else clause, and again the same thing... You see where this is going? Just remove `manageLocationPermission()` from this else clause

Comment: @MattDeveloper make sure you accept the answer that solves your question